# How do you selcet the specific cell in a QTableView

Tags: python, pyqt, qtableview

In Python, using a QTableView how do I get a specific cell and how do I set the current cell.

Comment: for those who feel I deserve a -1, how should this be improved?  As this was not an intuitive solution and I didn't see a question on here posted, so I wanted o help others.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To get a specific cell from the QTableView aka "index" use:

e.g. for cell[0,0]

```
m = self.tbl.model()
itm = m.index(0, 0)
```

and to set a current position use the position  you got above

```
sm = self.tbl.selectionModel()
sm.setCurrentIndex(itm, QItemSelectionModel.SelectionFlag.ClearAndSelect)
```